# Delete 400-layer folder by Java

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a File Manager for Android ,and I create 400-layer folder when write a copy method , i have fix the bug ,but i can't delete the folders have created by call delete() method.

My delete() method works well when delete normal folders but not work with the 400-layer folder.

my delete() method here

```java
 public boolean delete(File file) {
        boolean isSuccess = false;
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] fileArray = file.listFiles();
            for (File tFile : fileArray) {
                delete(tFile);
            }
            file.delete();
        } else {
            file.delete();
        }
        return isSuccess;
    }
```

Comment: It would have been a goo idea to more clearly describe what "doesn't work" really meant in your case. If it really was a simple NullPointerException, providing the error and stack trace would have making answering your question a lot easier.

Comment: Ok ,i will remember it

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it with a if(null) before recursive

```
public boolean delete(File file) {
    boolean isSuccess = false;
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        File[] fileArray = file.listFiles();
        //change here
        if (file != null) {
            for (File tFile : fileArray) {
                delete(tFile);
            }
        }
        file.delete();
    } else {
        file.delete();
    }
    return isSuccess;
}
```